# Java - While Loop keeps repeating for pizza program

Tags: java

I am a new java programmer and I am writing a pizza program in which I am trying to set and get the size of the pizza however I am getting stuck in a loop if the user inputs a wrong value. I want it to continue to keep asking the user to enter the size. If I can also get help in outputting the total price that'd be great to once I get the size and get the price from the Pizza2 class but if not I just am trying to at least fix this issue with the size getting stuck in a loop.

```
package hello;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza2Test 
{
    private static Scanner userInput; //declare scanner

    private static Pizza2 [] pizzaList; //declare pizzaList array

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //initalize scanner 

        System.out.print("Enter quantity of pizzas: "); //ask user to enter quantity of pizza
        int lQuantity = userInput.nextInt(); //store users input
        pizzaList = new Pizza2[lQuantity]; //creating a pizza list with quantity being the size of the array

        populatePizzaList(); 
        displayPizzaList();

        userInput.close(); //close scanner
    } 
    //populate the array with pizza information
    //
    private static void populatePizzaList ()
    {
        int numberOfToppings = 0;
        //System.out.println("Length of Array: " + pizzaList.length);
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < pizzaList.length; cnt++) //start at 0 and increment and loop until 1 less than pizzaLists length
        {
            Pizza2 myPizza = new Pizza2(); //call Pizza2 class
            System.out.print("Enter size of pizzas (enter '0' for Large or '1' for Medium or '2' for Small): "); //ask user to enter size
            myPizza.setSize(userInput.nextInt()); //store size from pizza2 class
            while(true)
            {
                if(myPizza.getSize() == 0)
                {
                    myPizza.getLARGE();
                    break;
                }
                else if (myPizza.getSize() == 1)
                {
                    myPizza.getMEDIUM();
                    break;
                }
                else if (myPizza.getSize() == 2)
                {
                    myPizza.getSMALL();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter '0' for Large or '1' for Medium or '2' for Small. ");
                }           
                }
            System.out.print("Enter number of toppings of pizzas: "); //ask user to enter number of toppings
            numberOfToppings = userInput.nextInt();
            String [] myToppings = new String[numberOfToppings];
            //myPizza.setNumberOfToppings(userInput.nextInt());//store user number of toppings
            //String [] myToppings = new String[myPizza.getNumberOfToppings()];
            //int pNumberOfToppings = myPizza.getNumberOfToppings();
            for (int i = 0; i < myToppings.length ; i++) //start at 0 and increment until number of toppings
            {
                System.out.print("Enter toppings: ");//ask user to enter toppings
                myToppings[i] = userInput.next();//store user toppings
            }
            myPizza.setToppings(myToppings);
            pizzaList [cnt] = myPizza;
        }
    }
    //display the array with pizza information from the pizza array list
    //
    private static void displayPizzaList ()//number of pizza information to display 
    {
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + pizzaList.length);//get quantity from stored value
        for (int j = 0; j < pizzaList.length; j++) //start at 0 and loop until pizza list length
        {
            System.out.println("Size: " + pizzaList[j].getSize());//get size from stored value
            System.out.println("Number Of Toppings: " + pizzaList[j].getNumberOfToppings());//get number of toppings from stored value
            String [] myToppings = pizzaList[j].getToppings();//get toppings from stored value
            for (int i = 0; i < myToppings.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Toppings: [" + (i+1) + "]: " + myToppings[i]);
            }
        }
    }       
}

package hello;

public class Pizza2 
{
    private int size;
    private String [] toppings;
    private int numberOfToppings;
    private double price;
    private final double LARGE = 13.99;
    private final double MEDIUM = 10.99;
    private final double SMALL = 7.99;
    private final double TOPPINGS = 0.50;

    public Pizza2()
    {

    }
    public void setSize (int pSize)
    {
        size = pSize;
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public void setToppings (String [] pToppings)
    {
        toppings = pToppings;
    }

    public String [] getToppings()
    {
        return toppings;
    }
    private void setNumberOfToppings ()
    {
        numberOfToppings = toppings.length;
    }

    public int getNumberOfToppings()
    {
        return numberOfToppings;
    }
    public void setPrice (double pPrice)
    {
        price = pPrice;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
    //  if(size )
        return price;
    }
    public double getLARGE() {
        return LARGE;
    }
    public double getMEDIUM() {
        return MEDIUM;
    }
    public double getSMALL() {
        return SMALL;
    }
    public double getTOPPINGS() {
        return TOPPINGS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have entered the `while (true)` loop with a "bad" size, you don't do anything to change the size, so you never break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I commented some of your code and rewrite them with easier approach.

Do you know For Each loop? it is much easier loop and perfect for your program.
If you don't know about it simply tell me, i'll explain it

What have i done :

- I usually don't create object arrays. So i created an ArrayList of the speific object type by using the diamond brackets

Ex - ArrayList stringArray=new ArrayList<>();

So in your case, ArrayList of pizza objects [pizza1,pizza2,pizza3]

My observations :

- Also i saw that number of toppings haven't been passed to the object pizza, so the number of toppings will be printed with the default value zero

Your goal- "I want it to continue to keep asking the user to enter the size"

- for that instead of making while(true), make it boolean,

  boolean status=true;
  while(status){
  if(){
  status=false;
  //instead of break; make the status false
  }else{
  status=true // so the while loop will iterate since the condition is 
  true}

Reply me back if you got any problems, cheers

---

### Code ##`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza2Test {

    private static Scanner userInput; //declare scanner
    private static ArrayList<Pizza2> pizzaList = new ArrayList<>();
    static int lQuantity;

//    private static Pizza2 [] pizzaList; //declare pizzaList array
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //initalize scanner 

        System.out.print("Enter quantity of pizzas: "); //ask user to enter quantity 
of pizza
        lQuantity = userInput.nextInt(); //store users input
//        pizzaList = new Pizza2[lQuantity]; //creating a pizza list with quantity 
being the size of the array

        populatePizzaList();        
        displayPizzaList();

        userInput.close(); //close scanner
    }

    //populate the array with pizza information
    //
    private static void populatePizzaList() {
        int numberOfToppings = 0;
        //System.out.println("Length of Array: " + pizzaList.length);
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < lQuantity; cnt++) //start at 0 and increment and loop 
until 1 less than pizzaLists length
        {
            Pizza2 myPizza = new Pizza2(); //call Pizza2 class
            System.out.print("Enter size of pizzas (enter '0' for Large or '1' for 
Medium or '2' for Small): "); //ask user to enter size
            myPizza.setSize(userInput.nextInt()); //store size from pizza2 class
            while (true) {
                if (myPizza.getSize() == 0) {
                    myPizza.getLARGE();
                    break;
                } else if (myPizza.getSize() == 1) {
                    myPizza.getMEDIUM();
                    break;
                } else if (myPizza.getSize() == 2) {
                    myPizza.getSMALL();
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Sorry you entered some invalid values, Please 
try again");

                    System.exit(0);                    
                }
//                else {
//                    System.out.println("Please enter '0' for Large or '1' for 
Medium or '2' for Small. ");
//                }                
            }
            System.out.print("Enter number of toppings of pizzas: "); //ask user to 
enter number of toppings
            numberOfToppings = userInput.nextInt();
            myPizza.setNumberOfToppings(numberOfToppings);
//            String [] myToppings = new String[numberOfToppings];

            //myPizza.setNumberOfToppings(userInput.nextInt());//store user number of 
toppings
            //String [] myToppings = new String[myPizza.getNumberOfToppings()];
            //int pNumberOfToppings = myPizza.getNumberOfToppings();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfToppings; i++) //start at 0 and increment 
until number of toppings
            {
                System.out.print("Enter toppings: ");//ask user to enter toppings
//                myToppings[i] = userInput.next();//store user toppings
//                myToppings.add(i, userInput.next());
                myPizza.setToppings(userInput.next());
            }
//            myPizza.setToppings(myToppings);
//            myPizza.setToppings(myToppings);
//            pizzaList [cnt] = myPizza;
            pizzaList.add(cnt, myPizza);
        }
    }

    //display the array with pizza information from the pizza array list
    //
    private static void displayPizzaList()//number of pizza information to display 
    {
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + pizzaList.size());//get quantity from 
stored value
        for (int j = 0; j < pizzaList.size(); j++) //start at 0 and loop until pizza 
list length
        {
//            System.out.println("Size: " + pizzaList[j].getSize());//get size from 
stored value

            System.out.println("Size: " + pizzaList.get(j).getSize());

//            System.out.println("Number Of Toppings: " + 
pizzaList[j].getNumberOfToppings());//get number of toppings from stored value
            System.out.println("Number of Toppings: " + 
pizzaList.get(j).getNumberOfToppings());

//            String [] myToppings = pizzaList[j].getToppings();//get toppings from 
stored value
            ArrayList myToppings2 = pizzaList.get(j).getToppings();

            for (int i = 0; i < myToppings2.size(); i++) {
//                System.out.println("Toppings: [" + (i+1) + "]: " + myToppings[i]);
                System.out.println("Toppings: [" + (i + 1) + "]: " + 
myToppings2.get(i));
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

AND the pizza object class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Pizza2 
{
    private int size;
//    private String [] toppings;
    private ArrayList<String>toppings=new ArrayList<>();
    private int numberOfToppings;
    private double price;
    private final double LARGE = 13.99;
    private final double MEDIUM = 10.99;
    private final double SMALL = 7.99;
    private final double TOPPINGS = 0.50;

    public Pizza2()
    {

    }
    public void setSize (int pSize)
    {
        size = pSize;
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
//    public void setToppings (String [] pToppings)
//    {
//        toppings = pToppings;
//    }
//
//    public String [] getToppings()
//    {
//        return toppings;
//    }
    public void setNumberOfToppings (int numberOfToppings)
    {
//        numberOfToppings = getToppings().length;
        this.numberOfToppings=numberOfToppings;
    }

    public int getNumberOfToppings()
    {
        return numberOfToppings;
    }
    public void setPrice (double pPrice)
    {
        price = pPrice;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
    //  if(size )
        return price;
    }
    public double getLARGE() {
        return LARGE;
    }
    public double getMEDIUM() {
        return MEDIUM;
    }
    public double getSMALL() {
        return SMALL;
    }
    public double getTOPPINGS() {
        return TOPPINGS;
    }

    /**
     * @return the toppings
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getToppings() {
        return toppings;
    }

    /**
     * @param toppings the toppings to set
     */
    public void setToppings(String topping) {
        this.toppings.add(topping);
    }
}
```